# mockito-kotlin whenever arguments - Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

For testing I wrote a wrapper for `ViewModelProviders.of(...).get(...)` so that I can supply a mock:

```
class MyViewModelProvider {
    fun <T : ViewModel> get(scope: Fragment, type: Class<T>) : T {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(scope).get(type)
    }

    ...
}
```

And then in my test:

Dagger TestModule:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock

...

fun provideMyViewModelProvider(): MyViewModelProvider {
        return mock()
}
```

And in my test class:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.any
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.anyOrNull
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.whenever
...
@Inject
lateinit var mockViewModelProvider: MyViewModelProvider
...
val mockViewModel = mock<MyViewModel>()

whenever(mockViewModelProvider.get(any<Fragment>(), any<Class<ViewModel>>())).thenReturn(mockViewModel)
...
```

However on the line with `whenever` I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter scope
```

I've tried a couple things:

1. Swapping `any<Fragment>(), any<Class<ViewModel>>())` with `anyOrNull<Fragment>(), anyOrNull<Class<ViewModel>>()` --> still get the same error
2. Tried using concrete references `whenever(mockViewModelProvider.get(myFragment, MyViewModel::class.java)).thenReturn(mockViewModel)` --> Calls actual method instead of mock

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: do you actually use [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)? Have you checked that you actually import from `com.nhaarman..` packages?

Comment: @Droidman Yes.  I updated the code above to show imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer:

The mocked function needs to be marked `open` or use mock-maker-inline.

https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null

Comment: marking the function as `open` had no effect for me (the class containing the function is also `open`)

Comment: same problem here